# Install Ubuntu partition problems

Tags: system-installation

Is our Local disk:D or Local Disk:E going to be formatted while installing linux on our computer (As Local Disk:C is our windows disk where program installs).

Comment: It needs to go somewhere. If you want to make sure nothing is formatted, use window's disk management to resize a partition and make some space for your linux. Or run live sessions from USB only....

Comment: Firstly the local disk D: and E: is a legacy from CP/M & DOS days that windows retains.  Ubuntu, like unix, mac os, doesn't use drive letters, and I suspect this 'concept' is your larger hurdle.  Ubuntu gives you full control over your drives, but by referencing them differently to your thinking, you risk making errors because of the difference. As Fiximan already suggested, you may want to resize using windows you already know creating free space, and let Ubuntu install in that free space (create its partition(s) there)

Comment: Windows can only be installed on NTFS partition unlike Linux which uses ext4 .
You can create an ext4 partition by using a 3rd party tool e.g "minitool partition wizard" on windows.
Pay attention to partitions sizes and labels while installing so you don't wipe a needed partition.